# How to trigger button print when open pdf file on acrobat reader plugin in IE11 browser

Tags: javascript, pdf, internet-explorer, printing, acrobat

I has a problem. 
A need using javascript trigger to print button on acrobat reader on IE11.
thanks everyone!

[Image for my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2NWi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, the acrobat reader is an Add-on for IE, we can't access it via JavaScript.

To print the PDF file using JavaScript, I suggest you could try to convert the PDF to Html or HTML5. Then display that in your browser and call document.print() to print it.

The project [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) already does a pretty good job to convert PDF to HTML. Please check it.